# Magento 2.3.0 After change production mode minify js and minify css not working it admin side

Tags: error, magento2.3, admin-panel, production-mode, minify

I have tried all commands on our Magento 2.3.0 website but I am getting issue after changing to production mode. So if anyone is facing this type of error, please reply to me the proper solution. Admin side is not clickable and getting below error on the console

```
TypeError: require is not a function
921eba372ebcf7d66b86f7adae7cab0606c79d7f0594d4b36501050683d2a99b:95:1
    <anonymous> https://XXXXX.co.uk/oasis18/admin/dashboard/index/key/921eba372ebcf7d66b86f7adae7cab0606c79d7f0594d4b36501050683d2a99b/:95

TypeError: require.config is not a function requirejs-config.js:57:9
```

Comment: Run: cache flush, di compile and static content deploy.

Comment: already i apply it but actually in our other server my  staging site working it when i change it production mode but when i apply production on live site there issue getting

Comment: Check console if css and js files are loading correctly or not. Also try to delete generated/code, generated/metadata, pub/static/adminhtml, pub/static/frontend, pub/static/_cache, pub/static/requirejs(if there), var/view_preprocessed, var/cache and var/page_cache. Then run di:compile and static content:deploy.

Comment: already i try this here console this error getting in admin side and frontend side same error getting

Comment: i am stuff this issue because in staging my site work properly after production mode but in client server there getting issue i am not clickable in magneto admin side only dashboard showing.

Comment: I am apply all command but not generate min js and min css in browser level in folder there store min js and min css.